# Vue.js: How the child components mutate the parent's state?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-component

In vuejs.org, there said:

> The two-way binding will sync the change of child’s msg property back to the parent’s parentMsg property. (Here is the [link](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Prop-Binding-Types).)

---

But I'm confused that how could I change child's property so that this change can be synced back to its parent?

---

### router

```
// Define rule of router.
router.map({
    '/categories': {
        // The List.vue
        component: CategoryList,

        subRoutes: {
            // ... some rules ...
            '/add': {
                // The DetailAdd.vue
                component: CategoryDetailAdd
            }
        }
    }
});
```

### List.vue (the parent)

```
<template>

    <tab v-bind:tabs="tabs" :active="active"></tab>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <router-view :categories="categories"></router-view>
    </div>

</template>
<script>

    var Tab = require('../common/Tab.vue');
    export default{
        components:{
            tab: Tab
        },
        data() {
            return {
                categories: [],
                tabs: [],
                active: '1'
            };
        },
        ready() {
            this.$http.get('/categories').then((response) => {
                // success
                this.$set('categories', response.data.categories);
                this.$set('tabs', response.data.tabs);
                this.$set('active', response.data.active);
        }, (response) => {
                // error
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

### DetailAdd.vue (the child)

```
<template>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/categories/add">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-md-2 control-label">name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">superiror</label>

            <formselect></formselect>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sort_order" class="col-md-2 control-label">sort</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="sort_order" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <formbutton></formbutton>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    var FormSelect = require('../common/FormSelect.vue');
    var FormButton = require('../common/FormButton.vue');

    export default{
        components: {
            formselect: FormSelect,
            formbutton: FormButton
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        $('.nav-tabs').on('ready', function() {
            $('.nav-tabs li').attr('class', '');
            $('.nav-tabs li:last').attr('class', 'active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

I just want to mutate the `active` property in parent (`List.vue`), how to achieve this?

Thank all of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two-way binding works as you might think it does: when you change a property in the parent, it gets changed in the children, and vice versa. Take a look at this as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/u0mmcyhk/1/, the children is able to change the state of the parent. If you remove `.sync` from the parent template, it stops working.

Having said that, `.sync` will be deprecated on 2.0, in favour of communication (`broadcast`, `dispatch`) or some state management like `vuex`.

More information: https://vuejs.org/api/#v-bind

Comment: Great! it's as what you said, just call **this.`property`** can access that property I want to mutate. Thank you again!